# Android, AlertDialog. How to access its title when clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

At some point, I need to queue Alertdialogs with questions to the user, waiting for him/her to answer them one by one.
The code would be something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<SomeValue; i++)
{
    Msg = "Do you want to add " + mylist.get(i) + " to the system?";
    AlertDialog ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
      .setTitle("New document " + mylist.get(i))
      .setMessage(Msg)
      .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // Function to develop

   }
   })
.setNegativeButton("Ignore", null)
.show();
}
```

So, developing for onClick function: how do I know there which is the Alertdialog associated? 
For example, how can I get to know, from the onClick function, what is the title of the current Alertdialog?

Comment: can someone help me with my query, if i want to add content description in title of above example with text "hello Amit". how i can do this, without custom view inflator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you can't access the default title so you'll need to set the title with :  `setCustomTitle(View v)` - just make it a simple layout XML file with you title `TextView`
 in it.

Cast the `DialogInterface` to `AlertDialog` in the `onClick()` method like this:

```
((AlertDialog)dialog)
```

now you can access whatever you want like that:

```
((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TITLE_TEXTVIEW_ID).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into DialogFragments. Create a class the extends DialogFragment. the onClickListener should have access to the fragments variables and methods - which could include a member variable for the title

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an anonymous inner class, there is only one `AlterDialog` which will call this `onClick()` method, namely the one that you are building. You don't need to detect which `Dialog`'s button was clicked since there is only one. If you need the title for some other reason, then feel free to use the other suggestions.